# Is there a better way of solving this problem other than guessing what the $2 \times 2$ matrices are?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

**EDIT**
I am just wondering whether, in this type of question, we would be allowed to assume that the ground field is algebraically closed, e.g., the complex numbers, so that we can look the Jordan form of matrices?  Please feel free to comment on this, if you'd like.

The Jordan form was the key point of the problem, for anyone interested in solving the below problem.

This is an old exam question from linear algebra that I am working on,

The problem statement is:

**Part 1**

Can you find $2×2$ matrices $A$,$B$, and $C$, so that $A^2≠0$, $B^2≠0$ and $C^2≠0$

but $AB=0$,$BC=0$ and $CA=0$?

**Part 2**

Can you find $2×2$ matrices $A$,$B$, and $C$, so that $A^2≠0$, $B^2≠0$ and $C^2≠0$

but $AB=0$,$AC=0$ and $BC=0$?

So far, I have spent a lot of time on this problem by naively playing around with simple $2x2$ matrices, but no combination of $3$ has worked yet.

Every time I think I've found a combination that works, it turns out that the square of one matrix is unfortunately the zero matrix, which disqualifies it from being used.

What is the real intent of this problem?  What concepts are being tested?  What is a good strategy?

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: +1 on Burde's answer. I will add that all matrices must have exactly one zero eigenvalue or else $A^2=AB(B^2)^{-1}BA=0$ (similarly for the others).

Comment: Well, $A^2 \neq 0 \iff \text{Im}(A)\not \subseteq \ker(A)$ and $AB=0 \iff \text{Im}(B)\subseteq \ker(A)$. Seems pretty straightforward from here.

Comment: Hi @bharb, I now understand your very cool second if and only if statement.  For your first i.f.f. statement, then under what conditions is the Image of A contained in the Kernel of A?  I am thinking *only* when A is the zero matrix.  Is this correct?  Thanks,

Comment: For instance $A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. The kernel of this matrix is $\ker (A)= \text{Im}(A)=\langle e_2 \rangle$. You can see it $A^2=AA$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Jordan decomposition for, say, $A$. Then we may assume that
$A$ is a diagonal matrix, or 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} a & 1 \cr 0 & a \end{pmatrix},
$$
with $a\neq 0$, because $A^2\neq 0$. Now it becomes an easy computation with $2\times 2$-matrices to find an example:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\;
B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \cr 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix},\;
C=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \cr 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Of course, $A^2,B^2,C^2\neq 0$, but $AB=BC=CA=0$. There are many solutions, even with $A$ diagonal.

The assumption $A^2\neq 0$ means that $A$ is not nilpotent, i.e., the characteristic polynomial is not $t^2$. Because of Cayley-Hamilton we know that $A^2-tr(A)A+\det(A)I=0$, so that not both $\det(A)$ and $tr(A)$ can be zero.

Edit: For the second part: If  $A=\begin{pmatrix} a & 1 \cr 0 & a \end{pmatrix}$, then $a\neq 0$ and the equations immediately give $B=0$, a contradiction. Now try the other case, where $A$ is diagonal. It gives immediately a contradiction.

Comment: Hi @DietrichBurde, why was putting $A$ into Jordan form the key step?  I mean, we still have to guess the matrices $B$ and $C$, which did not work well for me for a long time.  Does the Jordan form force something to happen?

Comment: The Jordan form, tracer and determinant make the equations to compute almost trivial. You could just write down all equations for $AB=BC=CA=0$ by hand.

Comment: Hi @DietrichBurde, what you gave, I think, is not a Jordan block, unless $a=b$.  If $a\ne b$, then there are two distinct eigenvalues, and the matrix, in Jordan form, is diagonal.  Or were you already implying this?  Sorry, I just want to be sure, thanks,

Comment: Hi @User001 You are right.

Comment: Thanks so much for the confirmation -- I will proceed with the problem now, @DietrichBurde,

Comment: The upper left entry of $CA$ is $-1$, isn't it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, a typo - thank you.

Comment: Hi @DietrichBurde, I have finished Part 1, your matrix A was a pretty key point, and from there, everything else was a breeze.  What do you think about Part 2?  My gut feeling is that no such matrices A,B,C exist...but it really is no more than just a speculation - I don't know where to start, so far...

Comment: @User001 Start again with the two possibilities for $A$ and just write down the equations in the coefficients of $A,B,C$. You will get a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, of course.  Wow, Considering two cases of A, either it must be diagonal or it has a Jordan form, makes the problem so simple -- AB=0 will force B=0, which is a contradiction.  One last thing @DietrichBurde, since the problem doesn't mention it, I am assuming that we'd be free to assume that the ground field is complex, so that the characteristic polynomials split, and that there *are* eigenvalues of each matrix to consider.  What do you think?  Thanks so much,

Comment: @User001 You may assume that the field is $\mathbb{C}$, because if there is no solution over $\mathbb{C}$, then there is no solution over $\mathbb{R}$. Conversely, our solution for part $1$ is even over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much for your awesome answer, @DietrichBurde.  Have a great day :-)

Comment: Another helpful initial observation here is that all of these matrices should have rank $1$.

Comment: Hi @omnomnomnom how can you see that?  It's clear that the matrices are *at least* of rank 1... thanks,

Comment: Oh because AB=0 shows that A has nontrivial null space - since B is not 0. And by rank-nullity theorem, A has rank 1.  Is that right, @omnomnomnom?  Thanks :-)

Comment: If $A$ has full rank, then $AB=0$ implies that $B=0$

Comment: Ah, right @Omnomnomnom; thanks so much for the cool observation.  Knowing this significantly cuts down the types of matrices I would have to experiment with to answer Part I.  I had spent a lot of time getting nowhere with blindly guessing and trying all sorts of simple 2x2 matrices - I knew there had to be some structure to this problem statement.  Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 1):

***Can*** I assume that the field is algebraically closed?

Yes. A zero (resp. nonzero) matrix in a base field is still a zero (resp. nonzero) matrix in any extension field. So, in both parts 1 and 2, you may assume without loss of generality that the underlying field is algebraically closed.

***Can*** I use Jordan form, without assuming that the field is algebraically closed?

Yes. Since $A$ is $2\times2$ with $A^2,B^2\ne0$ and $AB=0$, the matrix $A$ must be nonzero but singular. It follows from Cayley-Hamilton theorem that $A^2=\operatorname{tr}(A)A$ with $\operatorname{tr}(A)\ne0$. Therefore $x(x-\operatorname{tr}(A))$ --- a product of two distinct linear factors --- is an annihilating polynomial of $A$. In turn, $A$ is diagonalisable over the given base field. So you don't need any field extension to diagonalise $A$.

***Must*** I use Jordan form (or diagonalisation) to solve the problems?

No. Since $A$ is $2\times2$ with $A^2,B^2\ne0$ and $AB=0$, the matrix $A$ must have rank $1$. Similarly for $B$ and $C$. Let $A=x_1y_1^T,\ B=x_2y_2^T$ and $C=x_3y_3^T$. Then part 1 is equivalent to solving
\begin{cases}
y_1^Tx_1,\ y_2^Tx_2,\ y_3^Tx_3\ne0,\\
y_1^T x_2 = y_2^T x_3 = y_3^T x_1 = 0
\end{cases}
for some nonzero vectors $x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3$.
By a change of basis, you can further assume that $x_1=(1,0)^T$. Now the problem can be solved easily by simple inspection. In fact, under the assumption that $x_1=(1,0)^T$, it can be shown that $A,B,C$ must be, up to nonzero scalar multiples, in the form of
\begin{align*}
A&=\pmatrix{1\\ 0}\pmatrix{1&a}=\pmatrix{1&a\\ 0&0},\\
B&=\pmatrix{-a\\ 1}\pmatrix{1&-b}=\pmatrix{-a&ab\\ 1&-b},\\
C&=\pmatrix{b\\ 1}\pmatrix{0&1}=\pmatrix{0&b\\ 0&1}
\end{align*}
for some $a,b$ such that $b\ne-a$.

Using the same technique, we see that part 2 is equivalent to solving
\begin{cases}
y_1^Tx_1,\ y_2^Tx_2,\ y_3^Tx_3\ne0,\\
y_1^T x_2 = y_2^T x_3 = y_{\color{red}{1}}^T x_{\color{red}{3}} = 0.
\end{cases}
The equations $y_1^T x_2 = y_1^T x_3 = 0$ imply that $x_2,x_3$ are linearly dependent. In turn, the equations $y_1^T x_2 = y_2^T x_3 = 0$ imply that $y_1,y_2$ are linearly dependent. But then the requirements $y_2^Tx_2\ne0$ and $y_1^Tx_2=0$ are contradictory to each other. Therefore $A,B,C$ have no solutions.